# How to understand embedded kernel running for ARM versatile PCB which is nothing but a simple program

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux

I was reading this tutorial about running writing and debugging bare metal ARM software. So I like to know what the "software" term means in "writing and debugging bare metal ARM software". I'd like to know: can a simple program that does nothing but prints message to serial console in Arduino at register UART0 can it be called as kernel?

What I know kernel is tons of device drivers, etc. and lots of code. But I'd like to know if I have simple embedded device like Arduino then can a simple program that writes to memory mapped registers of device be qualified to be called kernel? Is the `-kernel` flag a must to supply to Qemu so author typed `-kernel` too and provided only the piece of code that is a simple program as kernel?

In the tutorial there are just 4 commands to make the build these are

```
$ arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g startup.s -o startup.o
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g test.c -o test.o
$ arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld test.o startup.o -o test.elf
$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
```

and ran in Qemu like

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -s -S -kernel test.bin
```

So test.bin is a simple program but its specified as kernel in qemu command. So I'd like to know does the test.c/test.bin only itself be qualified to be called kernel? Or is it just typed in the command to satisfy the qemu requirements since its for emulating linux image kernel?

https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/amp/

Also can this type of development be found in any other embedded device? I thought there suppose of be a boot loader and kernel separately for embedded devices that needed to be flashed to flash memory. But in the tutorial its just simple program, so why bootloader is not required because what I know bootloaders tells where to find the kernel image in flash memory.

Comment: Or is it `startup.s` is bootloader?

Comment: Unfortunately your post is far too broad to be answered in a satisfying way, and it contains multiple questions. You will learn more if you do some research by the common way, using your favorite web search engine, read the stuff you find, experiment a lot, and build some kind of understanding that there is rarely a fixed academic definition of such terms.

Comment: Anyway, in a nutshell: A **bootloader** is responsible to load an independent application that _could_ be a kernel. No computer _needs_ it actually, but it is a convenient way to make life easy. Chances are that your real Arduino contains a bootloader that checks that you have flashed an application, and enables you to overwrite that, without the need to use a dedicated in-system-programmer.

Comment: A **kernel** can be anything that supports applications, abstracting the hardware (search term "hardware abstraction layer"), the borders are blurry. If you write a simple application that runs stand-alone, I would not call it a kernel. And you don't need a bootloader to start it. Your module "startup" is simply the implementation of that part of the C standard that is necessary to call `c_entry()`. -- Qemu uses the option "-kernel" to load the first application to run. This _could_ be a kernel of a sophisticated operating system, and in your case it is your simple stand-alone application.

Comment: @thebusybee can u also please do tell doesn't linker script contain my program function names and start address of functions in memory layout ?

Comment: my gcc linker just says this but no function names with only tbss .data .debug

Comment: This is a complete new question. Please post a new one, and remember to include some [mre], for example the sources and linker script, and the exact error messages. SO is not a forum.

Comment: @busybee ok I asked please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286585/complete-garbage-gcc-producing-as-linker-script-in-linux-my-gcc-for-archetecture